# Oracle-17132 when passing a Char from storedFunction

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, spring-jdbc

I'm facing an issue with my StoredFunction. It looks trivial, but I don't see a way to fix it.

Oracle DB contains a function with following signature and some simple body

```
FUNCTION  MY_FUNC (CARD_NUM_IN in char, CARD_ID number default null) 
return number;
```

I execute call to the function as follows:

```
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource);
SqlParameterSource sps = new MapSqlParameterSource()
        .addValue("CARD_NUM_IN", ' ', OracleTypes.CHAR)
        .addValue("CARD_ID", Long.parseLong(cardId), OracleTypes.NUMBER);
simpleJdbcCall
        .withFunctionName("MY_FUNC")
        .withCatalogName(PACKAGE_NAME);

Object  result = simpleJdbcCall.executeFunction(Object.class, sps);
```

Result is:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: ORA-17132 Invalid conversion requested
```

If I remove the Char param from my function and stop passing it, stored function works as expected.

How should I pass a Char (function signature change is not possible)?

Comment: Strings (i.e. you CHAR parameter) should be enclosed into single quotes. What happens if you do that, i.e. prepare CARD_NUM_IN so that it doesn't look like `abcd` but `'abcd'`?

Comment: Thanks, I was passing java.lang.Character  instead of java.lang.String. Changing passed param to String solved the issue

Comment: Great! I'm glad you fixed it.